# In Linux how to forbid code execute in heap

Tags: linux-kernel, malloc

Image this way to invade Linux: 1. malloc a space. 2. write binary code to this region. 3. jump to this code.

I want to forbid this way to run code. Only run code in .text section.  What should I do to the Linux kernel? Thank you!

Comment: I believe that malloc (in most cases) should return memory area without exec permissions. Have you checked it?

Answer (score 0):

The PaX security patch to linux address this concern by ensuring that no memory in RAM is both writeable and executable. This ensures that one can not allocate memory into RAM, write code to it, and then execute it (which seems exactly what you are trying to prevent).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PaX#Executable_space_protections

Note that you may have to compile a custom kernel to install this patch. Alternatively, try seeing if your distribution offers a linux kernel with the patch installed. (Search for linux-grsec or linux-pax).